# Reusable items from a list in a card sorting task using R shiny and sortable libraries

Tags: r, shiny

Using the `sortable` library, I am trying to create a shiny page with columns where individuals sort items from a list.

I am struggling to make some of the items reusable. For example, using the window in the image below, I would like to drag the item named "One" to col1 and col2. Does anyone know how I could do this using the code below?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".bucket-list-container {min-height: 350px;}"))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      tags$b("Exercise"),
      width = 12,
      bucket_list(
        header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
        group_name = "bucket_list_group",
        orientation = "horizontal",
        add_rank_list(
          text = "Drag from here",
          labels = list(
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
          ),
          input_id = "rank_list_1"
        ),
        add_rank_list(
          text = "col1",
          labels = NULL,
          input_id = "rank_list_2"
        ),
        add_rank_list(
          text = "col2",
          labels = NULL,
          input_id = "rank_list_2"
        ),
        add_rank_list(
          text = "col3",
          labels = NULL,
          input_id = "rank_list_2"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

# server <- function(input,output) {
  output$results_1 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$rank_list_1 # This matches the input_id of the first rank list
    )
  output$results_2 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$rank_list_2 # This matches the input_id of the second rank list
    )
  output$results_3 <-
    renderPrint(
      input$bucket_list_group # Matches the group_name of the bucket list
    )
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This looks more like a select (a copy, sample with replacement) and move (to one or more buckets), than drag and drop, which seems to be sample without replacement, hence impeding drag and drop to two distinct locations. Sorry that this doesn't add much. [clone-able](https://rstudio.github.io/sortable/articles/cloning.html), seems to fit your use case.

Comment: http://rstudio.github.io/sortable/articles/cloning.html

Comment: @Andrie this works nicely. Is there any way to number or shade the lines? This is to sort tasks with items in each column parallel to each other. Hope that makes